# Implement Java interface in C# with IKVM?

Tags: ikvm

Let's say I have a JAR that defines the following classes:

```
public interface IFoo{
    public iBar getBar();
}

public interface IBar{
    public String getSomeString();
}

public class FooUser{
    public FooUser(IFoo foo){}
}
```

After I create a DLL from the JAR using IKVM, how do I create C# implementations of `IFoo` and `IBar` so that I can instantiate a `FooUser` in my C# program?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyFoo : IFoo {
  public iBar getBar() {
    return new MyBar();
  }
}

class MyBar : IBar {
  public String getSomeString() {
    return "some string";
  }
}
```

Duh! :-)